# AS3 TLFTextField : Differents background Color for some part of the text

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am new in AS3.
In my application I wanted to do some backgroundcolor in the output textField.

The Text within the textField has differents strings separated by a blank like this:

"AAA BBB CCC AAA BBB AAA CCC" .

- My big problem is:
  how to change to blue the **background color** of all **AAA**-Stings within the textField.

Please every suggestion will be helpfull. Two days now I am trying to solve it.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Use [setTextFormat()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#setTextFormat%28%29) to set formatting in anything other than uniform formatting. You have to parse your TF's `text` property for all the "AAA", "CCC" etc, and for each found instance you call `setTextFormat()` with approppriate format.

Comment: Hi Vesper thank you. Could you give me please an example in code. Please